Predicting simulated data for a known curve
I am a newbie here seeking advice on a mathematical problem I am currently having in my research.

I have a pre-existing curve created by extrapolating known fitted experimental data. As shown below, the x-axis is, say, heat given to the sample and y-axis is the response probability
Heat vs Response

I have another dataset for which I have to estimate the decay function. For sample "i" the total heat is defined as
$$
    H_{i} = H_{0}*exp^{-k*t} + H_{known} {1}
$$
where $H_{0}, t $ and $H_{known}$ are the known terms. "k" is the unknown term

$H_{i}$ generated from equation1 and its known binary response for all the samples are then binned to get H and response probability.

Below, I am showing a sample figure with green points as the new data, with a randomly picked "k" value.
Simulated data in green


My problem is the estimate of the unknown "k" in Equation 1, which minimizes the difference between the green points and the blue curve.
Can someone suggest a mathematical approach to estimate "k"
Many thanks for your help!
